# how to call jquery function with different <a href="">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call 2 different jquery functions to hide links

```
<a href="">.zip file, first link
</a>
<script>
$("a").click(function() {
location.href="first.location";
return false;
});
</script>

<a href="">.tar.gz file, second link
</a>

 <script>
 $("a").click(function() {
 location.href=="second.location";
 return false;
 });

 </script>
```

How can I call the 2 functions so that I call the first one clicking the first link and the second one clicking the second link?

Thanks a lo

Comment: You'd be better off giving those anchors an id, and use that to bind a click handler to them

Comment: You might also want to give your `href`s a `#` value

Comment: Are you doing anything else inside the event handlers? Because as it is, you don't need event handlers at all.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Rx5ej/1/

Answer (score 4):

This is not the best solution. For best results you might want to restructure your html and add some sort of classes and IDs to the links or their parent to identify them. But this will work

For the first link

```
$("a:eq(0)").click(function() {
location.href="first.location";
return false;
});
```

and for the second link

```
 $("a:eq(1)").click(function() {
 location.href=="second.location";
 return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set the `href` in the markup there is no need for `JQuery` or `Javascript`.

```
<a href="first.location">.zip file, first link
</a>

<a href="second.location">.tar.gz file, second link
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [:eq() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) here like:

```
// Clicking the first link
$("a:eq(0)").click(function () {
    location.href = "first.location";
    return false;
});

// Clicking the second link
$("a:eq(1)").click(function () {
    location.href = "second.location";
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like it has already been suggested the best way to do it is to have different id's for these a tags. But if for some reason you don't want to assign ids(why on earth would you do that?) you could do the following:

Wrap the anchor tags in a div and give it an id like this

```
 <div id="myDiv">
  <a href="#">First Link</a>
  <a href="#">Second Div</a>
 </div >
```

Then use jQuery to do the linking:

```
<script>
 $(function(){
   $("myDiv").children(a:first-child).click(function(){
      // Do stuff here
   });

   $("myDiv").children(a:last-child).click(function(){
      // Do stuff here
   });
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help:

```
<a id="first" href="">.zip file, first link</a>
<script>
  $("first").click(function() {
    location.href="first.location";
    return false;
  });
</script>

<a id="second" href="">.tar.gz file, second link </a>

<script>
  $("second").click(function() {
    location.href=="second.location";
    return false;
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can introduce an id attribute to your links. and then trigger the events based on the id of the element.

```
<a href="" id='link1'>.zip file, first link
</a>
<script>
$("#link1").click(function() {
location.href="first.location";
return false;
});
</script>

<a href="" id='link2'>.tar.gz file, second link
</a>

 <script>
 $("#link2").click(function() {
 location.href=="second.location";
 return false;
 });

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give link in html(href)

```
$("a").click(function()
{
    location.href = $(this).attr('href');
    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("a:eq(0)").click(function() {
location.href="first.location";
return false;
});`

`$("a:eq(1)").click(function() {
 location.href=="second.location";
 return false;
 });`